# Divide two divs by another curved/arched div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to create a website layout containing several full width pictures, which are aligned vertically. The pictures shall be seperated by a curved element, which ideally is created with HTML/CSS, as the width could change and the curve shall always fill the 100% width.

I have uploaded a visualization of my problem here:

[image: Problem image]

I have tried some stuff with the `border-radius`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/37u4c/34/ but the results are not quite what I want. The height of the element shall remain always 20 px, but with the round border it gets smaller at the edges....
Any tips or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I have tried some stuff with the border-radius" - post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this layout using border radius, the point is to make the element with border-radius wider than the viewport :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Jjmd2/)**

Output :

[image: Round separator of 2 images]

*HTML :*

```
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-9.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="round">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-7.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.round {
    position:absolute;
    width:200%;
    left:-50%; top:50%;
    border-top-left-radius:100%;
    border-top-right-radius:100%;
    border-top:20px solid #fff;
    border-right:20px solid #fff;
    border-left:20px solid #fff;
}
.round img {
    width:60%;
}
```

Comment: Looking quite like expected, except that the bend is very big. how would i make the arch a little flatter? expand the width of the round element even further?

Comment: @Maurice yes, like this for example : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Jjmd2/1/ (I also changed the way the images  are centered)

Comment: alright, i got it, now i just have to smoothen the arch, it looks a little stepped

Comment: @Maurice the anti-aliasing is browser related and you won't be able remove it completly. If it is an issue for you, your best bet is to use a `.png` image with transparency. You can also take a look at this article http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-get-smoother-rounded-corners/

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `border-radius` is that (imho) you can't get custom enough shapes.

A bit of googling got me to [this pen](http://codepen.io/lukeyphills/pen/FjygE).

I guess you could get what you want by creating an `svg` `path` element and using it as a separator (lines `36-44` of the html).

[PATH REFERENCE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with a border-radius, I've made an example of it for you right here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zvP7s/2/

The CSS looks as following:

```
.full-width img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.top-picture {
    height: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bottom-picture {
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 50%;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

However, it does not look quite as what you want, and that is because I think you should not do this with a border radius. You could create an image of the arc you want and position it between your images.

**EDIT**

I will post another example of border-radius as there might be another way to do this.

**EDIT 2**

Nevermind, it looks even worse.

Comment: Yeah, i ran into the same problem, that it does not look good on the outer edges, but thanks for trying. Sir Celsius came up with a promising solution

Comment: He sure did, looks like that's worth checking out.